# Creating a folder with timestamp

Tags: python

Currently am creating files using the below code,I want to create a directory based on the timestamp at that point in the cwd,save the directory location to a variable and then create the file in the newly created directory,does anyone have ideas on how can this be done?

```
def filecreation(list, filename):
    #print "list"
    with open(filename, 'w') as d:
        d.writelines(list)

def main():
    list=['1','2']
    filecreation(list,"list.txt")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You mean, something like this?

```
import os, datetime
mydir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S'))
os.makedirs(mydir)
with open(os.path.join(mydir, 'filename.txt'), 'w') as d:
    pass # ... etc ...
```

### Complete function

```
import errno
import os
from datetime import datetime

def filecreation(list, filename):
    mydir = os.path.join(
        os.getcwd(), 
        datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S'))
    try:
        os.makedirs(mydir)
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            raise  # This was not a "directory exist" error..
    with open(os.path.join(mydir, filename), 'w') as d:
        d.writelines(list)
```

**Update:** check `errno.EEXIST` constant instead of hard-coding the error number

Comment: @redShadow-Thanks,why are you checking for e.errno!=17?what does 17 indicate?

Comment: The OSError with number 17 is "directory exists" and as such you can ignore it in this case (you just need the directory to be there), but you don't want to ignore things like directory creation failed, etc.

Comment: Thanks RedShadow, appreciated.

Just as a reference for any coming person, this worked for me well, with tiny change required as follows:
.
from datetime import datetime as dt.
.
.
.
As a reference ...refer to the following comment for additional info.
{https://stackoverflow.com/a/32463688/3571619}