# "datetime": 'module' object has no attribute 'now'

Tags: python, datetime, attributes

I have a script that I run using the `from datetime import datetime` method. The first time that I run the script, the first call to `datetime.now()` throws the error. If I run it again it will sail through the rest without a problem.

Here is a snippet:

```
from datetime import datetime

tot_time = datetime.now() # It bonks on this line
```

Comment: Please provide a code snippet of the relevant parts

Comment: Do you also have just `import datetime`? Can you give a [mcve]?

Comment: from datetime import datetime

tot_time = datetime.now()

Answer (score 25):

If you are doing an `import *` after your `from datetime import datetime`, you could be overriding your `from` import with a plain `import datetime` from another module.

One way to find out if it is a namespace issue is to do the following:
`from datetime import datetime as dt`. Presumably, you won't collide with another `dt`.

Comment: Thanks Michael, appreciated.

Comment: `from datetime import datetime as dt` worked for me.

Comment: `from datetime import datetime as dt` worked when **the only other imports** were `from __future__ import print_function`, `from __future__ import with_statement`, `import csv` and `from random import randint`

Answer (score 1):

If `python -c "from datetime import datetime; datetime.now()"` fails then there is a stray `datetime.py` module in `sys.path`. Don't use stdlib names for your own modules. See *[The name shadowing trap](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-name-shadowing-trap)*.

Comment: that link has rotted unfortunately